# Unable to save report after using TotalPageCount

Tags: visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio installed.
After using TotalPageCount from the Special Fields or in a formula in a report, I am unable to save the report. I get no error messages, so I'm kind of lost here.
I'm trying to suppress a section on the last page of my report, and this is the suggested method in all searches I have done.
I also would like the PageNumber of TotalPageCount in my page footer, but I could live without that if that was my main problem.

Comment: This is only happens when you insert a totalpagecount ? On what section are setting that ? 
I had a similiar problem but only after exporting the report once the file would dissapear (bc the dispose wasn't working properly)

Comment: It happens when i use TotalPageCount field from Special Fields in a section (PageFooter) or if I use it in a formula like if (PageNumber = TotalPageCount ) then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should avoid using TotalPageCount in an expression (such as section suppression) that might impact the page count.

Instead, use something like OnLastRecord or similar logic.

Comment: Yes, problem is that I have a subreport with its own header section on the last page... I guess I need to change the subreport